# How to set FontFamily in code

Tags: wpf

I'm creating a WPF application where I need to use custom fonts. A created a font resource library as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx. An example shows how to set a font family in XAML:

```
<Run FontFamily="/FontLibrary;Component/#Kootenay" FontSize="36">
  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
</Run>
```

How do I set a font family in the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assign a Name to your run and then construct the FontFamily with the [URI constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602324.aspx):

Xaml:

```
<Run x:Name="MyTextRun">ABC</Run>
```

Code behind:

```
MyTextRun.FontFamily = new FontFamily(new Uri("/FontLibrary;Component/#Kootenay", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), "Kootenay");
MyTextRun.FontSize = 36;
```

Comment: There is no FontFamily contructor that takes 2 strings.

Comment: it does not work. I get Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: URI must be absolute.

and after I change to  UriKind.Absolute i get
Unhandled Exception: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Comment: Try switching to a full pack: URI format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

Comment: yeap that was it. the correct uri is

   new Uri ( "pack://application:,,,/FontLibrary;Component/#Kootenay", UriKind.Absolute )

Answer (score 1):

First, give your element a name.

```
<Run x:Name="someNameHere">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</Run>
```

and now in the code behind you can do set it like in the following examples:

```
someNameHere.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Monospace");
```

or

```
someNameHere.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Comic Sans MS");
```

or

```
someNameHere.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Times New Roman");
```